css on dropdown button
I'm getting some issue with buttom with dropdown style, this is the code:
<template>
  <div class="datatable-wrapper">
    <div class="table-container">
      <table class="table datatable-table is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-estatus" align="center">
              Action
            </th>
            <th class="col-estatus" align="center">
              id_client
            </th>
            <th class="col-estatus" align="center">
              client_txid
            </th>
            <th class="col-estatus" align="center">
              id_file
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            v-for="(item, index) in paginatedData"
            :key="index"
          >
            <td class="col-id-cliente" align="center">
              <VDropdown icon="feather:more-vertical">
                <template #content >
                  <div class="dropdown-item pointer" @click="viewDetails(item)"> Details </div>
                  <div class="dropdown-item pointer" @click="opction2"> Opcion 2 </div>
                  <div class="dropdown-item pointer" @click="opction3"> Opcion 3 </div>
                </template>
              </VDropdown>                
            </td>
            <td class="col-id-cliente" align="center">{{ item.id_client }}</td>
            <td class="col-id-beneficiario" align="center">{{ item.client_txid }}</td>
            <td class="col-id-cliente" align="center">{{ item.id_file }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <VFlexPagination
        v-model:current-page="page"
        :item-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        :total-items="data.length"
        :max-links-displayed="7"
        no-router
        class="mt-4"
      />
  </div>
</template>

when I clicked on action, I got this:

you can see that the dropdowns options don't see right
so I tried to use "position: absolute" on tag VDropdown  but the action option stay static, so when I scroll horizontal It is above the other columns, what can I do if I just want the dropdown opction see right

If one of the parents in the tree has the overflow css property set, the child will be cut off. Are you using a javascript framework like angular or react?

I'm using vue js

Perhaps you can use something like this. However I have no experience with vue

This is an overflow and/or z-index issue

Update your code with the following lines. I used inline CSS styles here, but you can also use internal or external CSS styles if preferred.
1) Go to your container Div:
<div class="table-container" style="overflow-x: auto;">

Explanation: This style allows horizontal scrolling.
2) Go to your "col-id-cliente" class:
<td class="col-id-cliente" align="center" style="position: relative;">

Explanation: We use this style to ensure that the dropdown is positioned relative to the table cell, allowing it to move with the cell content.
3) Go to your dropdown component:
<VDropdown icon="feather:more-vertical" style="position:absolute; right: 0; z-index: 999;">

Explanation: This style ensures the dropdown is correctly positioned within the cell and appears above other content by using "z-index".
Try applying these changes and see if they resolve the issue.

I updated the code like your example, and  don't change anything... it's so crazy this issue

Instead of directly applying 'position: absolute;' to the 'VDropdown', apply it to the dropdown content. Create another div called 'dropdown-menu'. As followings,
<template #content>     <div class="dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 999;">       <div class="dropdown-item pointer" @click="viewDetails(item)">Details</div>       //put the other two lines in here also.     </div>   </template>
As well as, add 'position: relative' to the 'table-container' class, as follows:
<div class="table-container" style="overflow-x: auto; position: relative;">
